# .loc indexing changes type

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

If I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with columns of different type (e.g. `int64` and `float64`), getting a single element from the `int` column with `.loc` indexing converts the output to `float`:

```
import pandas as pd
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'ints':[1,2,3], 'floats': [4.5,5.5,6.5]})

df_test['ints'].dtype
>>> dtype('int64')

df_test.loc[0,'ints']
>>> 1.0

type(df_test.loc[0,'ints'])
>>> numpy.float64
```

If I use `.at` for indexing, it doesn't happen:

```
type(df_test.at[0,'ints'])
>>> numpy.int64
```

It also doesn't happen when all the columns are `int`:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'ints':[1,2,3], 'ints2': [4,5,6]})
df_test.loc[0,'ints']
>>> 1
```

Is this a consequence of some core properties of `pandas` indexing? In other words, is it a bug of a feature? :)

**Update**: Turns out, [it *is* a bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11617) and it is going to be fixed in `pandas 0.20.0`.

Comment: I think it's to do with `loc` implicitly trying to return a row, even though you only have a single value to return the dtype is upcasted to the dtype that can represent these row values

Comment: @EdChum, IMO it's a correct answer. Why don't you post it as an answer with a small demo?

Comment: @MaxU sure will post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that `loc` is implicitly trying to return a `Series` initially even though you're returning a single column and hence a scalar value from that row the `dtype` is being upcasted to a dtype that will support all dtypes for that row, if you selected just that column and use `loc` then it wouldn't convert this:

```
In [83]:
df_test['ints'].loc[0]

Out[83]:
1
```

You can see what happens when you don't sub-select:

```
In [84]:
df_test.loc[0]

Out[84]:
floats    4.5
ints      1.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

This maybe undesirable and I think there maybe a github issue regarding this

this [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15231) is kinda related

Comment: Thanks! That issue is related indeed. It is funny that if the second column is `str`, it doesn't upcast single values to `object`, so `.loc` works correctly. It only upcasts if you're actually getting out a `Series`, like in your example.

Comment: Do you think I should link this question in the thread on Github to show another circumstance where it comes up?

Comment: Yeah I think it's worth showing inconsistencies like you stated

Comment: turns out, it is going to be fixed in the new version: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11617