# Prevent coercion of pandas data frames while indexing and inserting rows

Tags: python, pandas, coercion

I'm working with individual rows of pandas data frames, but I'm stumbling over coercion issues while indexing and inserting rows. Pandas seems to always want to coerce from a mixed int/float to all-float types, and I can't see any obvious controls on this behaviour.

For example, here is a simple data frame with `a` as `int` and `b` as `float`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__  # '0.25.2'

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2.2]})
print(df)
#    a    b
# 0  1  2.2
print(df.dtypes)
# a      int64
# b    float64
# dtype: object
```

Here is a coercion issue while indexing one row:

```
print(df.loc[0])
# a    1.0
# b    2.2
# Name: 0, dtype: float64
print(dict(df.loc[0]))
# {'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.2}
```

And here is a coercion issue while inserting one row:

```
df.loc[1] = {'a': 5, 'b': 4.4}
print(df)
#      a    b
# 0  1.0  2.2
# 1  5.0  4.4
print(df.dtypes)
# a    float64
# b    float64
# dtype: object
```

In both instances, I want the `a` column to remain as an integer type, rather than being coerced to a float type.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11617), but I could not found if effectively the issue was solved. In the mean time I guess you could do: `df.loc[[0], df.columns]`

Comment: Duplicates? [.loc indexing changes type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43366763/7851470) & [Adding row to pandas DataFrame changes dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22044766/7851470).

Comment: Sounds like pd.DataFrame doesn't support type mixing on instantiation?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

dtype param only supports a single type.

`.read_[type]` supports multiple dtypes though...

Answer (score 4):

After some digging, here are some terribly ugly workarounds. (A better answer will be accepted.)

A quirk [found here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11617#issuecomment-216767947) is that non-numeric columns stops coercion, so here is how to index one row to a `dict`:

```
dict(df.assign(_='').loc[0].drop('_', axis=0))
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2.2}
```

And inserting a row can be done by creating a new data frame with one row:

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'a': 5, 'b': 4.4}, index=[1]))
print(df)
#    a    b
# 0  1  2.2
# 1  5  4.4
```

Both of these tricks are not optimised for large data frames, so I would greatly appreciate a better answer!

Comment: You could always just coerce post append `df['a'] = df.a.astype(mytype)`... It's still dirty though and probably not efficient.

Comment: `.astype()` is dangerous for float -> integer; it has no problem changing `1.1` to `1`, so you really need to be sure all of your values are 'integer-like' before doing it. Probably best to use `pd.to_numeric` with `downcast='integer'`

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you are getting data from dataframe or appending data to a dataframe and need to keep the data type same, avoid conversion to other internal structures which are not aware of the data types needed.

When you do `df.loc[0]` it converts to [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html),

```
>>> type(df.loc[0])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

And now, `Series` will only have a single `dtype`. Thus coercing `int` to `float`.

Instead keep structure as [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html),

```
>>> type(df.loc[[0]])  # NOTE the braces [[]]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Select row needed as a frame and then convert to `dict`

```
>>> df.loc[[0]].to_dict(orient='records')
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2.2}]
```

Similarly, to add a new row, Use pandas [`pd.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) function,

```
>>> df = df.append([{'a': 5, 'b': 4.4}]) # NOTE: To append as a row, use []
   a    b
0  1  2.2
0  5  4.4
```

The above will not cause type conversion,

```
>>> df.dtypes
a      int64
b    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Wow had to read that second code block three times to get it.  That is very subtle.  This is much better than what I've done in the past... loop through the final dataframe and reassign the values with the correct data type (yes what I did is a horrible solution that really won't scale.).

Answer (score 2):

The root of the problem is that

1. The indexing of pandas dataframe returns a pandas series

We can see that:

```
type(df.loc[0])
# pandas.core.series.Series
```

And a series can only have one dtype, in your case either int64 or float64.

There are two workarounds come to my head:

```
print(df.loc[[0]])
# this will return a dataframe instead of series
# so the result will be
#    a    b
# 0  1  2.2

# but the dictionary is hard to read
print(dict(df.loc[[0]]))
# {'a': 0    1
# Name: a, dtype: int64, 'b': 0    2.2
# Name: b, dtype: float64}
```

or

```
print(df.astype(object).loc[0])
# this will change the type of value to object first and then print
# so the result will be
# a      1
# b    2.2
# Name: 0, dtype: object

print(dict(df.astype(object).loc[0]))
# in this way the dictionary is as expected
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2.2}
```

2. When you append a dictionary to a dataframe, it will convert the dictionary to a **Series** first and then append. (So the same problem happens again)

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L6973

```
if isinstance(other, dict):
    other = Series(other)
```

So your walkaround is actually a solid one, or else we could:

```
df.append(pd.Series({'a': 5, 'b': 4.4}, dtype=object, name=1))
#    a    b
# 0  1  2.2
# 1  5  4.4
```

Comment: Good idea to use `object` data types! Another one is to create an object DataFrame from the beginning: `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2.2]}, dtype=object)`

Answer (score 1):

A different approach with slight data manipulations:

Assume you have a list of dictionaries (or dataframes)

`lod=[{'a': [1], 'b': [2.2]},  {'a': [5], 'b': [4.4]}]`

where each dictionary represents a row (note the lists in the second dictionary). Then you can create a dataframe easily via:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(dct) for dct in lod])
   a    b
0  1  2.2
0  5  4.4
```

and you maintain the types of the columns. See [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

So if you have a dataframe and a list of dicts, you could just use

```
pd.concat([df] + [pd.DataFrame(dct) for dct in lod])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you can work with the [nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#nullable-integer-data-type). The Series selection doesn't coerce to `float` and values are placed in an `object` container. The dictionary is then properly created, with the underlying value stored as a `np.int64`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2.2]})
df['a'] = df['a'].astype('Int64')

d = dict(df.loc[0])
#{'a': 1, 'b': 2.2}

type(d['a'])
#numpy.int64
```

With your syntax, this *almost* works for the second case too, but this upcasts to `object`, so not great:

```
df.loc[1] = {'a': 5, 'b': 4.4}
#   a    b
#0  1  2.2
#1  5  4.4

df.dtypes
#a     object
#b    float64
#dtype: object
```

However, we can make a small change to the syntax for adding a row at the end (with a RangeIndex) and now types are dealt with properly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2.2]})
df['a'] = df['a'].astype('Int64')

df.loc[df.shape[0], :] = [5, 4.4]
#   a    b
#0  1  2.2
#1  5  4.4

df.dtypes
#a      Int64
#b    float64
#dtype: object
```